# What is a fast way to preview a MySQL join?

Tags: mysql, sql, optimization, join

I'm working on a project involving joins between datasets and we have a requirement to allow previews of arbitrary joins between arbitrary datasets. Which is crazy, but thats why its fun. This is use facing so given a join I want to show ~10 rows of results quickly.

I've been basing my experimentation around different ways to sub-sample the different tables in such a way that I get at least a few result rows but keep the samples small enough that the join is fast and not cause the sampling to be expensive.

Here are the methods I've found pass the smell test. I would like to know a few things about them:

1. What types of joins or datasets would these fail at?
2. How could I identify those datasets?
3. If both of these are bad at the same thing, how could they be improved?
4. Is there a type of sampling I have not put here that is better?

#### Subselect with a limit.

Takes a random sample of one dataset to reduce the overall size.

```
SELECT col1, col2 FROM table1 JOIN
  (SELECT col1, col2 FROM table2 LIMIT #) AS sample2 
    on table1.col1 = sample2.col1
  LIMIT 10;
```

I like this because its easy and there is potential in the future to be smart about which table to samples from. It is also possible to select a portion where table1.col1 never equals sample2.col1 so no results are returned.

#### Find equals values of col1 and Sample them

More complicated, multi-query approach. Here I would do a distinct select of the columns to join on, compare the results to find common values and then do a subselect limiting the results to the common values.

```
SELECT DISTINCT col1 FROM table1;
SELECT DISTINCT col1 FROM table2;
commonVals = intersection of above results
SELECT col1, col2 FROM table1 JOIN 
  (SELECT col1, col2 FROM table2 WHERE col1 IN(commonVals) LIMIT #) as sample2
    on table1.col1 = sample2.col1 
  LIMIT 10;
```

This gets us a good sample of table2, but the select distinct query may be more expensive than the join. I believe there may be a way to determine if this method is faster if you knew something about how long the distinct cals would take but at this point we don't have that much knowledge of the datasets.

#### Slap a LIMIT on the join

This is the easiest and the one I'm leaning towards.

```
SELECT col1, col1 FROM table1 join table2 on table1.col1 = table2.col1 LIMIT #
```

Assuming the join is good, this will always return data and for at least a large set of cases it will do it fast.

Comment: You've shown 3 answers to a problem but haven't really asked your question.

Comment: You are very right. I've updated the problem with some specific questions.

Comment: All of your solutions would work, but I guess you are looking for the fastest one. As long as you don't have any ordering in the SQL you should be using the 3rd option ("Slap a LIMIT on the join"), as it just picks up the first few records quickly. BUT if you have ordering in the SQL then it need to join all rows, do the ordering and then limit it - which obviously will take a lot longer on the server (although the network traffic is the same, as it is only sending the first few rows, but I guess you concern is more the server performance than the network one).

Comment: Do not go with the 2nd, it requires full table scans of both tables for DISTINCT. Investigate random sampling techniques, I don't know how MySql does that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem with the first approach is that the rows in the first table might not have a match in the second table.  Remember, inner joins not only do matching, they also do filtering.

The second approach could work, if all the columns used for joining have indexes on them.  You can then get a list of matching ids by doing something like:

```
where id in (select id from table1) and id in (select id from table2) . . .
```

This gets rid of the initial code and should be pretty fast.

The third method is using the capabilities of the database most directly.  You would be depending on the ability of MySQL to optimize according to the size of the result set.  This is something that it does, at least in theory.

I would strongly recommend the third approach in conjunction with indexes on the columns used in the joins.  This requires minimal changes to the query (just add a `limit` clause).  It allows the database to pursue additional optimizations, if appropriate.  It works on a more general set of queries.

Comment: I decided that the database knows best and just put the limit on it. This doesn't work for everything so I'm also adding somewhat aggressive timeouts and putting in fallback code that knows how to handle them.